# How to add the tier price in quantity range

Tags: magento2.3, tierprice

I am using Magento 2.3

I have created one simple product and added tier price.I want to set the tier price in quantity range.ex .1-5 qty price is 6$, 6-11 qty price is 4$.

Can anyone guide me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html, it will help you set up and understand tier pricing.

Answer (score 0):

You can define product quantity starting range and price. Special price will be applied if product falls in the quantity range. For more details refer [Price tier documentation](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html)

Admin configuration:

[image]

Product with in range of mentioned quantity

[image]

Product quantity not in the range:

[image]